# how to find AIC values for both models using R software?

Tags: statistics, self-learning, statistical-inference, regression, regression-analysis

I'm studying survival analysis.

I estimated both Cox regression model and Buckley&James regression model.

In order to determine which model is better for my dataset, I used Akaike Information Criteria (AIC). Well, How to find AIC values for both models using R software?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a *coxph* object (the Cox regression) you can use the *extractAIC* command from the *stats* package.
For more details see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/extractAIC.html).

Comment: Thank you :) I found it for Cox regression. But, when I do it for Buckley&James estimator, I get the massage "numeric(0)".

Comment: What does that message mean? How to find AIC for Buckley James regression? My real question is that. Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not familiar with this model. I guess this message mean that there is no AIC value for you to extract. If you have the value of the likelihood you can compute the AIC by $2k - 2\ln (\mathcal{L})$.